# face_detector not detecting faces

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have successfully built face_detector package with catkin_make and fixed the launch file's depth and rgb topic based on [Face Detector Example Usage](http://wiki.ros.org/face_detector#Example_Usage).

Besides this, I made a `face_detection_behavior` node which subscribes to topic `/face_detector/people_tracker_measurements_array` and `/face_detector/faces_cloud`.

```
rostopic info /face_detector/people_tracker_measurements_array 
Type: people_msgs/PositionMeasurementArray

Publishers: 
 * /face_detector (http://192.168.31.164:43851/)

Subscribers: 
 * /face_detection_behavior (http://192.168.31.164:45399/)

rostopic info /face_detector/faces_cloud
Type: sensor_msgs/PointCloud

Publishers: 
 * /face_detector (http://192.168.31.164:43851/)

Subscribers: 
 * /face_detection_behavior (http://192.168.31.164:45399/)
```

However, no faces can be detected.

```
rostopic echo /face_detector/faces_cloud
rostopic echo /face_detector/people_tracker_measurements_ar
```

The above returns no messages.

This is my face_detector launch file:

```
<launch>                                                                                  
  1 
  2   <arg name="camera" default="camera" />
  3   <arg name="depth_ns" default="depth_registered" />
  4   <arg name="rgb_ns" default="rgb" />
  5   <arg name="image_topic" default="image_rect_color" />
  6   <arg name="depth_topic" default="image_rect_raw" />
  7   <arg name="fixed_frame" default="/camera_rgb_optical_frame" />
  8 
  9   <!--include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch"/-->
 10   <node name="$(anon dynparam)" pkg="dynamic_reconfigure" type="dynparam" args="set_from_p
    arameters $(arg camera)/driver">
 11     <param name="depth_registration" type="bool" value="true" />
 12   </node>
 13 
 14  <node pkg="face_detector" type="face_detector" name="face_detector" output="screen">
 15     <remap from="camera" to="$(arg camera)" />
 16     <remap from="image_topic" to="$(arg image_topic)" />
 17     <remap from="depth_topic" to="/hw_registered/$(arg depth_topic)" />
 18     <remap from="depth_ns" to="$(arg depth_ns)" />
 19     <remap from="rgb_ns" to="$(arg rgb_ns)" />
 20     <param name="fixed_frame" type="string" value="$(arg fixed_frame)" />
 21     <param name="classifier_name" type="string" value="frontalface" />
 22     <rosparam command="load" file="$(find face_detector)/param/classifier.yaml"/>
 23     <param name="classifier_reliability" type="double" value="0.9"/>
 24     <param name="do_continuous" type="bool" value="true" />
 25     <param name="do_publish_faces_of_unknown_size" type="bool" value="true" />
 26     <param name="do_display" type="bool" value="true" />
 27     <param name="use_rgbd" type="bool" value="true" />
 28     <param name="approximate_sync" type="bool" value="true" />
 29 
 30   </node>
 31 
 32 </launch>
```

---

Here is what I have checked:
face detector node:

```
rosnode info /face_detector
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node [/face_detector]
Publications: 
 * /face_detector/faces_cloud [sensor_msgs/PointCloud]
 * /face_detector/feedback [face_detector/FaceDetectorActionFeedback]
 * /face_detector/people_tracker_measurements_array [people_msgs/PositionMeasurementArray]
 * /face_detector/result [face_detector/FaceDetectorActionResult]
 * /face_detector/status [actionlib_msgs/GoalStatusArray]
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]

Subscriptions: 
 * /camera/depth_registered/camera_info [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo]
 * /camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw [sensor_msgs/Image]
 * /camera/rgb/camera_info [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo]
 * /camera/rgb/image_rect_color [sensor_msgs/Image]
 * /face_detector/cancel [unknown type]
 * /face_detector/goal [unknown type]
 * /tf [tf2_msgs/TFMessage]
 * /tf_static [unknown type]

Services: 
 * /face_detector/get_loggers
 * /face_detector/set_logger_level
```

camera depth image_rect_raw node:

```
rostopic info /camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw
Type: sensor_msgs/Image

Publishers: 
 * /camera/camera_nodelet_manager (http://192.168.31.135:38017/)

Subscribers: 
 * /face_detector (http://192.168.31.164:43851/)
```

camera rgb image_rect_color node:

```
rostopic info /camera/rgb/image_rect_color
Type: sensor_msgs/Image

Publishers: 
 * /camera/camera_nodelet_manager (http://192.168.31.135:38017/)

Subscribers: 
 * /face_detector (http://192.168.31.164:43851/)
```

The cascade file I'm using is from [Haar cascades, Frontal Face](http://alereimondo.no-ip.org/OpenCV/34/). What could be the problem here?

Edit: Using Kinect and openni_launch package.

Edit2: I could not found the cause of the problem. But I have manually applied haar's cascade using the rgb and depth topic published from openni_launch and face detection seems to be working.

Regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318981/face_detector-not-detecting-faces/) by [ZeroSan](https://answers.ros.org/users/38110/zerosan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2019-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't seem to find to find the root cause of the problem. However, I created a face detector ROS package that uses's Haar's cascade and [CV Bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython).

This approach works for my use case.

---

Edit: Solution

I created a node that subscribes to `/camera/rgb/image_raw` and `/camera/depth/image_raw`.

The ROI of detected face can be obtained by applying Haar's cascade to Kinect's RGB image channel. Then, the same ROI is used to get the Depth image of detected face. This Depth image is used to compute the 3D point cloud (x, y, z) of the detected face.

```
RGB image callback:

 1. Convert RGB image message data to cv2 image.
 2. Apply Haar's cascade to the converted cv2 image to obtain the ROI of detected face.
```

Since now you know ROI of the face, you can basically use this ROI on the Depth image channel.

```
Depth image callback:

 1. Convert Depth image message data to cv2 image.
 2. Apply the ROI of detected face to the converted cv2 image.
 3. Convert the depth image to 3D point cloud data.
```

Use this [CV Bridge guide](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython) to convert raw image message data to cv2 image.

As for converting the depth image to point cloud, I referred to this [Conference Paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258442068_Method_to_convert_Kinect%27s_3D_depth_data_to_a_2D_map_for_indoor_SLAM). For convenience, the multiplier constant `M_x` and `M_y` was not given in the paper however I found it some time ago at some forum.

```
Multiplier of X coordinate = 1.12032
Multiplier of Y coordinate = 0.84024
```

If successful, you should be getting three coordinates (x, y and z) which is basically the point cloud of detected face.

---

Originally posted by [ZeroSan](https://answers.ros.org/users/38110/zerosan/) with karma: 55 on 2019-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SometimesButMaybe](https://answers.ros.org/users/45138/sometimesbutmaybe/) on 2019-08-25**:
Hi, can you share the package (or at least a small guide)?
Thanks!

**Comment by [ZeroSan](https://answers.ros.org/users/38110/zerosan/) on 2019-08-26**:
@SometimesButMaybe: I edited my answer.